# Is this solution correct

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Given $A+B=\frac{\pi}{4}$, find $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)$

My attempt:

Since $\tan(A+B)=1=\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\tan (B)}$, therefore $\tan(A)+\tan(B)+\tan(A)\tan(B)=1$, therefore, $1+\tan(A)+\tan(B)+\tan(A)\tan(B)=2$ Is it correct?

Comment: yes. it seems correct to me.

Comment: Basically correct, but perhaps you should exclude cases where A or B is of the form $(n+1/2)\pi$, e.g. A = $\pi/2$, B = $-\pi/4$.